# android vs android.support packages

Tags: android

**Question:**
When should be used android.support.* packages, and when android.*?

**Would love next facts considered while answering:**

- Not required to support old android versions
- ViewPager and other features available in support-only are desired
- If it can always be done in support, then why bother with native library?
- Can support/native library be disabled in IDE, so that I stop accidentally importing wrong packages?

Comment: Use the support libraries whenever needed. You don't have to go all or nothing.

Comment: @kentarosu that is what I believed. but once I insert a 'support' into  native or vice-versa it 'infects' everything around and I end up having to refactor whole project.

Answer (score 2):

Support library is used to make your app capable to run on android lower versions also.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to know, but I blame my bad questioning.

Comment: could you have a look at revised question?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely read the documentation.
android.support.* is used to support older devices that does not have new Android API.
For example, `Fragment`s were introduced from HONEYCOMB, that's why you should use support package, if you are planning to support Android 2.*.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to know, but I blame my bad questioning.